# How do I clear out-of-quote content from a Boxes-type InputField?

Tags: boxes, inputfield, sting

I have this code as a test.

```
Manipulate[in, 
Row[{ EventHandler[Style[Control@{{in, "\"N[Pi,10]\""}, InputField[#, Boxes] &,    
   Alignment -> {Left, Center},
   ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 10}}, ContinuousAction -> True,
   FrameMargins -> 10, ImageSize -> {600, 50}} , 20],
 {"MenuCommand", "HandleShiftReturn"} :> {    in  },
PassEventsDown -> False, Method -> "Queued"] }] ]
```

As above, I must use the InputField[#, Boxes] format.

Of course, in quotation marks, my input value is well recognized and printed as a string.

However, if spaces appear outside the quotation marks or letters or numbers are written, they are no longer recognized as strings.

[image]

I only want to get the value entered in the quotation marks.

In other words, in the example above, I only want to get "N[Pi, 10]".

And if possible, I hope that the content outside the quotation marks within InputField will be automatically erased when executed.

How do I clear out-of-quote content from a Boxes-type InputField?

Comment: If you only care about strings, why exactly do you need to use `InputField[...,Boxes]`?

Comment: I will type a command like "Plot[x,{x,-1,1}" in InputField. And I will save it as an Enterprise CDF and use it in Wolfram Player. At this time, if I use InputField[...,String], I can't completely input the command statement. I chose InputField[...,Boxes] as an alternative to this, and in this case it works very well.